# Disable flashing scroll bar of a UITableViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, scroll, uitableview

I have a `UITableViewController`, and I'd like to make it not flash the vertical scroll bar when I go back from a push action segue on one of it's cells (popping the view controller and going back to the `UITableViewController`).

It seems that, if the table has many rows (mine has around 20 with 60 points height each, so bigger than the screen), when I go back, it always flashes the vertical scroll bar once to show where it is in the table. However, I don't want that to happen, but I do want to keep the scrollbar around so it shows when the user scrolls. Therefore, disabling it completely is not an option.

Is this default behavior and can I disable it temporarily?

Comment: Why don't you want the flashing? It is standard behavior that users expect to see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:** Please, look at [Cezar’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22358005/2445863) below, which gives a nice workaround without any of the drawbacks of my proposals.

---

According to the documentation it is a behaviour of `UITableViewController`:

> When the table view has appeared, the controller flashes the table view’s scroll indicators. The `UITableViewController` class implements this in the superclass method `viewDidAppear:`.

So I think you have two options:

1. You can avoid using `UITableViewController` and start using a naked `UIViewController`. Rebuilding the functionality of `UITableViewController` from `UIViewController` is not that hard (you can follow this [old article](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2009/03/recreating-uitableviewcontroller-to.html) as reference).
2. Override `viewDidAppear:` and don’t call `[super viewDidAppear:animated]`. The problem here is that you don’t know what else does `UITableViewController` do when `viewDidAppear:` is called, so you might break something.

Comment: An easy way to do #1 is to create said view controller, add a table view, then when you create the custom class file, choose UITableViewController, then modify `UITableViewController` to `UIViewController` on the interface line in the .h file. You'll then have your delegate protocols and your skeleton delegate methods already there. Just don't forget to set the delegate properties to Files Owner for the UITableView in Interface Builder to hook things up.

Answer (score 11):

There is a simpler solution that doesn't require avoiding using a `UITableViewController` subclass.

You can override `viewDidAppear:` as stated by http://stackoverflow.com/users/2445863/yonosoytu, but there is no need to refrain from calling `[super viewDidAppear:animated]`. Simply disable the vertical scrolling indicator before doing so, and then enable it back afterwards.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    self.tableView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    self.tableView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = YES;
}
```

If you're using Interface Builder, you can disable the `Shows Vertical Indicator` option on the `tableView` for your `UIViewController` and enable it in code as shown above.

Comment: This works fine on iOS 9, but does not prevent the flashing on iOS 10.

Answer (score 3):

To get [Cezar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22358005/2445863) to work for iOS10 I had to include a (sizeable) delay before re-enabling the scroll indicator. This looks a bit strange if someone tries to scroll before the second is up, so you can re-enable the scroll indicator as soon as someone scrolls.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    tableView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
        self.tableView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = true
    }
}

override func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if !tableView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator {
        tableView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = true
    }
}
```

Actually, on thinking about it, you don't even need the delay, just do this:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    tableView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
}

override func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if !tableView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator {
        tableView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = true
    }
}
```

Comment: Sadly the last snippet has not been working for me in iOS 12.